# git-sync using github personal access token (PAT) for git submodules

Tags: git, github, airflow, git-sync

I have a Github repo which I configure in git-sync to sync files with my Kubernetes airflow instance by specifying the repo URL with PAT token like below:

```
https://<PAT>@github.com/org/dag_repo.git`
```

(PAT token is inserted by CI/CD and not committed to github to the dag_repo)

This Github repo also has multiple other GitHub Repos added as git submodules using the command:

```
git submodule add https://<PAT>@github.com/org/test-git-sync.git
```

My `.gitmodules` file looks like the below:

```
[submodule "test-git-sync"]
    path = test-git-sync
    url = https://<PAT>@github.com/org/test-git-sync.git
```

So in the submodule file git is saving the PAT token which is sensitive - thus I cannot commit it to Github

I tried adding the submodule repo without a PAT token - but in this case, git-sync is not able to check out the submodule because the submodule repo is private and no auth is specified.

- Is there a way to configure git-sync to use the same PAT token used in main repo to checkout submodules also ?
- Is it possible to parametrize the PAT token in the `.gitmodules` file and then git-sync can inject PAT during run-time?

Comment: I think you should be able to specify your git url as `https://github.com/org/dag_repo.git` (notice no PAT in URL) -- and similarly with submodule URLs -- and then use a credentials helper to provide the credentials to git. Leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because I don't have time check this and provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to provide relative paths in the git submodule to use the same repo config as the parent. In my case the below config in `.gitmodules` file made it work:

```
[submodule "test-git-sync"]
    path = test-git-sync
    url = ../test-git-sync.git # use relative path
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had the submodule set up with a temporary read-only PAT to begin with so when I changed the .gitmodules file I had to run `git submodule sync --recursive` before I could could push.